# I cant locate a button with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have tried `driver.find_element_by_class/css_selector/x_path`, but nothing can locate the button, the button is not in a iframe.
URL is [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/l30kif/your_dog_has_heard_all_of_your_conversations/).

I'm trying to click the button that shows more Comments.

Button HTML looks like this:

```
<button role="button" tabindex="0" class="j9NixHqtN2j8SKHcdJ0om _3t7aUZU2b2KWwDQkfT2eHl _10BQ7pjWbeYP63SAPNS8Ts HNozj_dKjQZ59ZsfEegz8 _2nelDm85zKKmuD94NequP0">View Entire Discussion (5.7k Comments)</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this information not enough to help you

Comment: Im also sorry its my first time asking a Question on here what can i add ? @dimay

Comment: try to add URL and what you are trying

Comment: i added the URL and a bit of context @dimay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select this `button`by `xpath` set it to:

> //*[text()[contains(.,'View Entire Discussion')]]

It is looking for text that contains *View Entire Discussion* or more specific:

> //button[text()[contains(.,'View Entire Discussion')]]

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()[contains(.,'View Entire Discussion')]]').click()
```